# Filter multiple R data.table columns to eliminate outliers

Tags: r, data.table, outliers

I want to eliminate outliers above or below 2 standard deviations, for many variables with similar names (too many to specify individually in the code).

```
library(data.table)

irisdt <- data.table(iris)
myCols <- grep("Sepal", colnames(irisdt), value=TRUE) 

# This works if I specify one column, 
# but I have too many columns to specify, so need to use grep approach.
irisdt[, Sepal.Length.Outlier := (scale(Sepal.Length) < -2 | scale(Sepal.Length) > 2)]

# This does not work
irisdt[, (myCols) := lapply(myCols, function(x) {(scale(x) < -2 | scale(x) > 2)} )] 

# This partially works, but changes in place
irisdt[, (myCols) := lapply(myCols, function(x) {(scale(irisdt[[x]]) < -2 | scale(irisdt[[x]]) > 2)} )] 
# How do I make new variables, for example "Sepal.Length.Outlier"?

myOutlierCols <- grep(".Outlier", colnames(irisdt), value=TRUE) 

# How do I select rows matching multiple columns (&)? 
irisdt[myOutlierCols=="FALSE"] # does not work
irisdt[, hasOutlier := lapply(myCols, myCols==TRUE)] # does not work
irisdt[hasOutlier=="FALSE"] # relies on line above, which doesn't work
```

Perhaps a function could take a data.table column and strip it of values above or below a z-score cutoff. That could be used with lapply.

```
# This does not work
removeOutliers <- function(myColumn, cutoff = 3) {
  lapply(myColumn, function (x) {
    if (scale(myColumn[[x]]) < -cutoff | scale(myColumn[[x]]) > cutoff) {
      x <- NA #specify individual value instead of column?
    } 
  })
}
removeOutliers(irisdt[,Sepal.Length]) # for testing
trimmedIrisdt <- irisdt[,lapply(.SD, removeOutliers(.SD)), .SDcols = myCols] # could do by = grouping variable

# Once outliers are made NA, this would work:
trimmedIrisdt <- complete.cases(trimmedIrisdt)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this achieves the goal:

```
irisdt[, keep := 
  as.logical(do.call(pmin, lapply(.SD, function(x) abs(scale(x)) <= 2)))
, .SDcols = myCols]

res = irisdt[(keep), !"keep"]

     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
135:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
136:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
137:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
138:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
139:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

This should also work fine if there are grouping variables. I don't know about its statistical soundness.

---

*How it works:*

1. Test each cell for `abs(scale(x)) <= 2`.
2. If the minimum result across columns is TRUE, then keep the row.

To see how it works cell-by-cell...

```
library(data.table)

mynewCols = paste0(myCols,"_outly")
irisdt[, (mynewCols) := 
  lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, abs(scale(x)) <= 2, NA))
, .SDcols = myCols]
```

Then browse like `View(irisdt[rowSums(!is.na(irisdt[, ..mynewCols])) > 0])`.

Comment: Thank you for the very concise and clear answer. It is much better than the approach I was going for!

Comment: I'm trying to modify it to replace all values 
abs(scale(x)) >= 2 with NA.

Here's my attempt (doesn't work):
irisdt[, (myCols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ( if (as.logical(do.call(pmin, lapply(.SD, function(x) abs(scale(x)) <= 2))))  
                                                  {NA} else {x}) )
       , .SDcols = myCols]

Comment: Also this does not work to replace cells: irisdt[, (myCols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {if (abs(scale(x)) <= 2) {x} else {NA}}), .SDcols = myCols] . Could you explain the do.call(pmin, ...)?

Comment: @KayleSawyer I'm not sure I follow. If you just use the `lapply` part, it should give a list of columns (instead of collapsing to one). You can alter the function to something like `replace(x, condition, NA)` or `{is.na(x) <- condition; x}`. I've edited to show what that looks like. `do.call(pmin, L)` takes the elementwise minimum across a list of vectors `L`. Btw, we could discuss it in the R chat room if there's a lot more to it https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: That explains it, thanks. The replace() function is great. This very useful code I can adapt.

Comment: With your current code in the lower part of your solution it works if you flip the unequality around from <= to >=. Currently, you are setting everything that is not an outlier to NA.

Comment: @Frank Could you please explain better what scale(x) does in the context of the lower code block? I'm a bit confused about that...